# Exposing fields in a class

Tags: c#, class, parameters

I am new to c# and object coding so please be gentle....

I have a class call LED, see below:

```
public sealed class LED
{
    public GpioPinValue ReqPinValue { get; set; }     //Enable/Disable LED
    public bool Flashing { get; set; }      //Does the LED flash
    public GpioPin Pin { get; set; }
    public int flashingPeriod { get; set; } //Period to flash in seconds



    private GpioPinValue value; //Pin value (high/low)
    private int flashCount = 0; //Times we have entered the timer loop


    public LED()
    {
    }

    public void UpdateLED()
    {
        int timesToCycle = 0;

        if (ReqPinValue == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {
            if (Flashing)
            {
                timesToCycle = flashingPeriod * 2;
                if (flashCount == timesToCycle)
                {
                    value = (value == GpioPinValue.High) ? GpioPinValue.Low : GpioPinValue.High;
                    Pin.Write(value);
                    flashCount = 0;
                }
                else
                    flashCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                Pin.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Pin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        }
    }

}
```

In another class I create four instances of this LED class for 4 different Status LED'S.

```
public sealed class StatusLED
{
    private const int RUN_LED = 4;
    private const int IO_LED = 17;
    private const int NET_LED = 27;
    private const int FAULT_LED = 22;

    public LED RunLed = new LED();
    public LED IOLed = new LED();
    public LED NetLed = new LED();
    public LED FaultLed = new LED();

    private GPIO GPIO = new GPIO();
    private GpioController gpioController;

    private ThreadPoolTimer timer;


    public void InitStatusLED()
    {
        gpioController = GPIO.InitGPIO();

        if (gpioController == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to find GPIO Controller!");
            //TODO proper error handling although this should never happen
        }
        else
        {
            //Setup the default parameters for the LEDS (ie flashing or non-flashing)
            RunLed.Flashing = false;
            IOLed.Flashing = false;
            NetLed.Flashing = false;
            FaultLed.Flashing = false;

            RunLed.flashingPeriod = 0;
            IOLed.flashingPeriod = 0;
            NetLed.flashingPeriod = 0;
            FaultLed.flashingPeriod = 0;

            RunLed.Pin = GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController, RUN_LED);
            IOLed.Pin = GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController, IO_LED);
            NetLed.Pin = GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController, NET_LED);
            FaultLed.Pin = GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController, FAULT_LED);

            //Turn the LED's on to Start
            RunLed.ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
            IOLed.ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
            NetLed.ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
            FaultLed.ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;

            timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(Timer_Tick, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        }
    }
    private void Timer_Tick(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
    {
        RunLed.UpdateLED();
        IOLed.UpdateLED();
        NetLed.UpdateLED();
        FaultLed.UpdateLED();
    }
}
```

I now want to set the field "ReqPinValue" for these instances in the StatusLED class from another class using the code below

```
private StatusLED statusLED = new StatusLED();

statusLED.RunLed.ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Type '....' contains externally visible field '....'  Fields
>   can be exposed only by structures.

I can see it doesn't like the line below being public, how can I can access a parameter of this instance from another class without making it public?

```
public LED RunLed = new LED();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make these *properties* rather than fields:

```
public LED RunLed {get;set;}
public LED IOLed {get;set;}
public LED NetLed {get;set;}
public LED FaultLed {get;set;}
```

Then, in your `InitStatusLED` method, initialize them:

```
public void InitStatusLED()
{
    gpioController = GPIO.InitGPIO();

    if (gpioController == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to find GPIO Controller!");
        //TODO proper error handling although this should never happen
    }
    else
    {
        //Setup the default parameters for the LEDS (ie flashing or non-flashing)
        RunLed = new LED(GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController, RUN_LED));
        IOLed = new LED(GPIO.InitOutputPin(gpioController,IO_LED));
        //And so on
```

But wait - your `LED` class doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `GpioPin`. Let's fix that too:

```
public sealed class LED
{
    public GpioPinValue ReqPinValue { get; set; }     //Enable/Disable LED
    public bool Flashing { get; set; }      //Does the LED flash
    public GpioPin Pin { get; set; }
    public int flashingPeriod { get; set; } //Period to flash in seconds



    private GpioPinValue value; //Pin value (high/low)
    private int flashCount = 0; //Times we have entered the timer loop


    public LED(GpioPin pin)
    {
        Pin = pin;
        Flashing = false;
        flashingPeriod = 0;
        ReqPinValue = GpioPinValue.Low;
    }
```

And see how we've eliminated a whole load of *repetitive* code from you `InitStatusLed` method too.

Having done all of this, go back and look at your properties again. For those which should only be set *by the class itself*, and not by any other code *using* the class, make the setters `private`:

```
public GpioPin Pin { get; private set; }
```